# Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client service can not start on Windows 7 64 bit system

Tags: windows-7, vpn, cisco-anyconnect

I am using "Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client v3.1.04059" to establish a VPN connection to a campus network at a university.
When I start the VPN client (vpnui.exe) I receive the following error message:

> VPN service not available.
>   The VPN agent service is not responding.
>   Please restart this application after a minute.

However, when I try to start the required service - called "Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Agent"- manually (using admin privileges) I get this error:

> Windows could not start the Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Agent
>   service on Local Computer.    Error 1067: The process terminated
>   unexpectedly.

I get the same error when trying to start the service over an admin command prompt (`net start "Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Agent"`).

I have uninstalled and reinstalled the VPN client several times, which didn't help.

The problem first appeared when an auto-update to the latest version of Cisco AnyConnect was performed (which is not optional, but happens automatically every time the vpn client is started, so going back to the previous version does not work...).

How can solve this issue? What am I missing?

EDIT: I have uninstalled my avast antivirus software now and deactivated windows firewall. To my surprise the problem is still there, so it is not related to Avast antivir as I thought at the beginning.

Comment: I can't help you with Avast, but I would suggest you look at Microsoft Security Essentials, which is free. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows/security-essentials-download

Comment: Thanks, but switching to another antivir software should only be a last resort solution at the moment.

Comment: Did you happen to solve this problem? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Nope, but I found that the problem is related to the latest version of Cisco Anyconnect only, which can not be avoided due to automatic updating... My "solution" was to switch to ordinary Cisco VPN Client (fortunately I still had the required certificate).  The antivirus software was not the issue in the end, since the VPN did still not work even after uninstalling avira...

Answer (score 9):

well I have a fix for you, but its not 100% but it will get it working.

Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services
Right Click Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Agent and choose start.
Then run the client and connect

The root of the problem is its not respecting automatic start-up in Windows 8 cause the TCP/IP connector is handled differently in Windows 8 to get windows to start up faster. So upon start and coming out of sleep, it reverts back to stopped again. So upon every start-up you have to do this.

Comment: Worked for me. I don't think it was a sleep issue, because my computer never sleeps. I got a slightly different "The application was unable to start correctly" in vpnui.exe after rebooting for updates. Restarting that service fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue and have found a real solution.

1. Uninstall the Cisco AnyConnect Mobility Client from Programs and Features.

   This will require a reboot afterwards. When the machine comes back online after the reboot,
2. Navigate to and DELETE the following folder:

   ```
   C:\ProgramData\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\Network Access Manager
   ```
3. After you have deleted this folder, reinstall Cisco AnyConnect.
4. The install will require another restart.

After the restart, AnyConnect should be installed and working properly.

Answer (score 0):

actually, once we uninstalled it, the Network Access Manager folder was gone.  we removed the next folder up, C:\ProgramData\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\ then reinstalled and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the Cisco anyconnect. I solved it by following steps:

1. Goto start and search for cisco anyconnect program then right click on it and **open file location**.
2. Once you get the shortcut file location, right click and select **Troubleshoot compatibility**
3. The window will try to detect problem and select **Try recommended settings**
4. Then click **Test the program**. Then you will see that you get the cisco login popping up. Then Select **yes, save these settings for this program**. You problem solved.